# CorelDRAW X6 16.0 underline not printed

Tags: print-design, corel-draw

I am designing a simple text document with some bolded and underlined text but when I print it the underline on one part of the text is not printed.

The font size of the text is 6.315pt.

The text in question is bolded as well but even when I unbold it it still doesn't show the underline.

Here is an image of the print, the text in question is "сух яйчен прах меланж":
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed by moving the text a few pixels down.

Comment: If you've answered your own question please mark it as the accepted answer.